# Moving and Hiding data in SSRS 2008 and 2012

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have created a Matrix is SSRS with the first column being todays date and the second column being same date last year. I have provided a sample below. YOU will see JUne 1 2014 and next to it june 2013. I would like hide the june 2 2013 and slide the data to the left to fill the empty space under june 1 2013 to have four rows of data. It did not past over well the row of 3 is 2014 and the row of 1 2013 .  Any suggestions?  I have not found any samples of such. thanks ahead of time.

Jun  1 2014     Jun  2 2013     Jun  2 2014     Jun  3 2013 
3,465       12,575
3,465       12,575
1,480       10,396
    1,287       11,208
6,514       23,642
6,514       23,642
6,893       21,617
    6,702       19,716
5,086       18,460
5,086       18,460
4,353       16,299
    3,543       11,723
1,067       3,874
1,067       3,874
559     2,562
    94      216
933     3,388
933     3,388
764     3,425
    71      159

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the column visibility for the column you want to hide to Hidden=true. If your question is more complex than the answer above you might want to look into using a column group over days in your data and hiding specific days in the data.